# How to customise the default time-stamp in blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I require some help with the customisation of the time-stamp in blogger. I have included the html coding for the time-stamp below:

```
  <div class='post-timestamp'>
    <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
      <data:top.timestampLabel/>
      <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
        <meta expr:content='data:post.canonicalUrl' itemprop='url'/>
        <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
      </b:if>
 </b:if>
 </div>
```

Ideally I would like to remove the word "at" from the front of the time-stamp. To resolve this issue I changed the settings on Dashboard > Layout > Main Edit , by removing the word and then saving the changes. However this doesn't seem to apply to the blog.

the second issue I'm having is that by default the time-stamp in blogger is a direct link to the blog post that it 'represents'. I wish to remove the direct link. I tried applying the following css coding:

```
.timestamp-link {
display: none!important;
 }
```

However this only makes the timestamp disappear. Whereas I only want the direct link to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To hide the word 'at' from Time-Stamp, just remove `<data:top.timestampLabel/>` in the code.

2) Link to post can be removed by deleting `expr:href='data:post.url'` inside `<a>` tag.

```
 <div class='post-timestamp'>
    <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
      <!--<data:top.timestampLabel/>  Remove this tag to hide 'at' from Time-Stamp -->
      <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
        <meta expr:content='data:post.canonicalUrl' itemprop='url'/>
        <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
        <!--delete expr:href='data:post.url' to remove link to the post-->
      </b:if>
     </b:if>
 </div>
```